# Using Variables in Shortcodes

Tags: shortcode

I'm trying to create a Shortcode to display scores between to teams. I've got this far, but I can't seem to get variables into the damn thing. I thought the arrays where used for that, but apparently it doesn't work like that.

```
 function get_gamecentre($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            "HOME-IMG" => '',
            "AWAY-IMG" => '',
            "HOME-NAME" => '',
            "AWAY-NAME" => '',
            "HOME-POINTS" => '',
            "AWAY-POINTS" => '',
    ), $atts));
    return '<div style="background-color: #360000;width: 670px; height: 250px; color: white; padding: 10px;">';
    return '<table style="color: white;" width="100%">';
    return '<tbody>';
    return '<tr>';
    return '<td style="text-align: center;" width="340"><img class="size-full wp-image-32 alignnone aligncenter" title="tribes-pp" src="'.$HOME-IMG.'" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>';
    return '<td width="34"></td>';
    return '<td width="350"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-32 aligncenter" src="'.$AWAY-IMG.'" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></a></td>';
    return '</tr>';
    return '<tr>';
    return '<td style="text-align: center;">[box color=red]'.$HOME-NAME.'[/box]</td>';
    return '<td style="text-align: center;">VS</td>';
    return '<td style="text-align: center;">[box color=red]'.$AWAY-NAME.'[/box]</td>';
    return '</tr>';
    return '<tr>';
    return '<td style="text-align: center;">[box color=green]'.$HOME-POINTS.'[/box]</td>';
    return '<td style="text-align: center;">VS</td>';
    return '<td style="text-align: center;">[box color=red]'.$AWAY-POINTS.'[/box]</td>';
    return '</tr>';
    return '</tbody>';
    return '</table>';
}
add_shortcode("gamecentre", "get_gamecentre");
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply don't call `return` more than once.

Just add your output to a variable:

```
$some_variable_name = 'mention the = at the beginning of this line';
$some_variable_name .= 'Take a look at the .Period before the = in this line';
$some_variable_name .= 'then add more lines always with the period';
// at the end of your shortcode function:
// if you want to echo something:
echo $some_variable_name;
// or:
return print $some_variable_name;
// If you want to just return it in code:
return $some_variable_name;
```

Also #1: Keep your variable names with lowerspace characters.

Also #2: In php, variables always have to use `_` underline instead of `-` dash.

Comment: I tried this instead. But it doesn't really work either... I'm not getting really along with the PHP :s

Comment: I guess you should edit your question and show us how you're calling the shortcode. Oh, and remove the other `[box]` shortcode. Make small steps first.